# Windows Update thinks battery saver is on, even when it's not

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I let my Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2 run out of battery, and now Windows Update thinks that Battery Saver is on (and won't install updates), even though the battery has fully recharged and Battery Saver is off.

I've checked the internet, and I've seen other people with the same problem, but nobody has a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I presume you have attempted a restart?

Comment: check in your bios, some bios have settings for battery management and for some reason the setting in your bios may be set on power saver.

Comment: @Ramhound I've restarted; shutdown, waited, & restarted; restarted with the volume up button held down; and a couple of other things.  No dice.

Comment: @Xavierjazz it's the OEM battery.  It's not user-replaceable.

Comment: having the same problem now, restarting/mode switching/etc do not resolve the issue. will check out the bios feature, but will also monitor this thread and update when possible.

Comment: Try this: (1) In Control Panel / Hardware and Sound / Power Options, choose High performance, (2) In Settings, Battery Saver, set it to off and  check in Battery saver settings the value of Turn battery saver on automatically if my battery falls below. Reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: I have not checked out the bios feature, but after a few days the problem resolved itself somehow (download started automatically). Still, I'll keep the bounty on the question for a good resolve for future reference.

Comment: @harrymc I also had the problem resolve itself, without any particular clue as to why it started working.  Sigh.

Comment: I guess, since it resolved itself on 2 computers at the same time, that it was fixed by some Windows 10 update happening in the background.

Comment: `has fully recharged and Battery Saver is off` what about leaving the a/c power connected?

Comment: @JorritReedijk does your PC have an application called energy manager? It ships with many lenovo PCs...

Comment: I have a Lenovo Yoga 700, Do you have Lenovo Settings App? Within that it has it's own 'Battery Saver'. Windows 10 has its own built in battery saver in the Settings app also, I would ensure these are both off. Furthermore, ensure you have 'Lenovo Energy Management' Installed.

Answer (score -1):

I got the updates working again (in a roundabout way).
I turned my battery-saver off/on manually didn't help,
I then disabled Microsoft Surface ACPI in Windows Device Manager did not help either.
I then turned everything back on and after a day or so the updates started downloading again.